# When using ES6, how can an imported function be undefined in one file, and not in another?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, redux

I'm using babel / ES6 with webpack. I'm importing the same 'actions' file - which exports a bunch functions - in two different places. At one place it returns a module, the other `undefined`:

actions.js

```
export function test() { ... }
export function test2() { ... }
```

App.js

```
import actions from './actions'
class App extends React.Component { ... }
console.log(actions);         //<--------  Object{test:function,test2:function)
export default connect((state) => { ... },actions)(App);
```

**edit**
the reason App.js worked was because it was actually using `import * as actions` as sugested below, I just retyped it wrong in the example

NestedComponent.js

```
import actions from './actions'
class NestedComponent extends OtherComponent { ... }
console.log(actions);         //<--------  logs undefined
export default connect((state) => { ... },actions)(NestedComponent);
```

Is this related to the order in which webpack defines the modules/files?

Comment: Are you sure that actions is present in the same directory as NestedComponent?

Comment: no it's actually in a nested folder in my setup, but I've double checked the path, and both the editor and the babel compiler complain if I change it (meaning it was good)

Comment: @Felix King is right though. Since you are not using default exports in the actions file, you wouldnt be able to import anything from it, unless you used a named import.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This shouldn't work in either case because you are importing the wrong values. `import foo from '...'` imports the **default** export of the module, but you don't have a default export, you only have named exports.

What you should use is

```
import {test, test2} from './actions';
// or
import * as actions from './actions';
```

Comment: Ah yes you're right, that was the problem. I use ```import * as actions from './actions'``` now and it works perfect. tnx!

Answer (score 32):

I ran into a similar issue, caused by circular dependencies. Tried to import a constant in file 'A' from file 'B' which in turn tried to import from file 'A'.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me. To find circular dependencies run `npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./`
Taken from this article: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/locate-circular-dependencies-in-typescript-modules-2b1eb03dbf2e

Comment: Thanks to you both! Fixed my headache after hours of confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Another common case where this happens is if you're testing with Jest and auto-mocking behavior is enabled.  Much grief, such gotcha.